# Heroku Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku

I'm facing Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 error in Heroku. My app uses 11.0.14 SDK, which is listed in the official Heroku site https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support as a supported version.

I've created a system.properties file and set the version there:

```
java.runtime.version=11.0.14
```

Also in pom.xml is the Heroku plugin added and the proper Java version everywhere specified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>app</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <processTypes>
            <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/app</web>
          </processTypes>
          <appName>app</appName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Still nothing has changed, locally it's working but I keep getting this error on Heroku. What else can I do?

Comment: what version is your jdk?

Comment: it's jdk-11.0.14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Heroku recommendation is to set the major version

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

This will resolve to the supported `11.0.14.1`, see [Heroku Java versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions).

Note: the file `system.properties` must be in the root of the repository.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Is `system.properties` in the root of the project?

Comment: It's in `src/main/resources`, same place as `application.properties`

Comment: It must be on the root of your project, I will update the answer

Comment: That was the problem, now it works, thank you!